# What am I missing in this use of fgets?

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

If I run the below code with scanf, it returns a string if it's in the tracks array. According to the book Head First C, this should work with fgets but returns nothing for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 80

char tracks[][MAX] = {
    "The Girl from Ipanema",
    "Here Comes the Sun",
    "Wonderwall",
    "You Belong To Me",
    "Everlong",
};

void find_track(char search_for[])
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if(strstr(tracks[i], search_for)) {
            printf("Track %d: %s\n", i, tracks[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char search_for[MAX];
    printf("Search for: ");
    //scanf("%79s", search_for);
    fgets(search_for, MAX, stdin);
    find_track(search_for);
    return 0;
}
```

Input looks like the following:

```
./tracks
Search for: 
Here
```

Nothing happens

Comment: Post the **exact** input you give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because `fgets` will also read the newline, i.e. `'\n'`. In more details:

If you type `Girl<enter>` then `search_for`will contain the characters:  `'G' 'i' 'r' 'l'
 '\n'` However, your `tracks` only contain `'G' 'i' 'r' 'l'` without the `'\n'`.

Consequently you will not find a matching substring.

Try changing:

```
fgets(search_for, MAX, stdin);
```

into

```
fgets(search_for, MAX, stdin);
if (strlen(search_for) > 0) search_for[strlen(search_for)-1] = '\0';
```

to remove the trailing newline

**Edit based on comments**

It's true that (depending on your OS/environment) the input stream can be terminated without a newline (ctrl-z, ctrl-d on some systems). If that is done the above code is insufficient. It needs an extra check like:

```
if (strlen(search_for) > 0 && search_for[strlen(search_for)-1] == '\n')
    search_for[strlen(search_for)-1] = '\0';
```

to make sure that only a "newline" is converted to a string termination.

Comment: Where is the newline coming from though? When I hit enter?

Comment: @RyanMc yes, when you hit enter the newline gets saved into the string

Comment: @RyanMc See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html  It says: **If a newline is read, it is stored into the
       buffer.**

Comment: Thanks this worked. Kinda bugs me that the book said it works though.

Comment: @RyanMc Well, I don't know that book but the manual is clear about this. It's an important difference between `scanf` and `fgets`

Comment: Actually '\n' may not be present if user terminates input with Ctrl-D. Probably this also must be checked when overwriting last character with '\0'.

Comment: @purec The string read will also lack a newline if the the line entered is longer than the number of characters that will fit in the buffer.

Comment: [A much simpler and more accurate way to remove a newline from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/4756299): `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;`

Comment: @AndrewHenle It may seem "much simpler" to you but have you ever looked what's really going on inside `strcspn`? It's correct that you save a few keyboard clicks. But the resulting code... what's more maintainable? The first time you saw that code, did you have to look up what `strcspn` was? Or did you just knew? KIS is a good principle.

Comment: @4386427 *It may seem "much simpler" to you* Your `if`statement with two conditions, one including a call to `strlen`, seems "simpler" to you?  Really? *have you ever looked what's really going on inside `strcspn`?*  Who cares?  Have you ever looked at what's going on inside the startup code that gets called before your program even reaches `main()`? *The first time you saw that code, did you have to look up what `strcspn` was?*  The first time you saw `strlen()` you had to either be told what it does, or look that up, too.  As did every single person who writes C code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle If you really think that most C programmers know `strcspn` just as good as they know `strlen` then fine - just use it. It'll never go into the code base I manage. EOD.

Comment: @4386427 So your standard for code is:  "If I don't know it, you can't use it."  You're limiting other developers based on the limits of what you know? Seriously?  Do you sit in code reviews and say "I don't know what this function does.  You have to remove it."? Of course, now that you know what `strcspn` does, you'll let it be used in the code base you manage?  Right?  EOD indeed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You can't end a discussion with multiple questions so I'll answer. It's not for the reasons you insinuate but for simplicity. So the answer is **no**, I don't turn down code because I don't know it. I'll turn down code that isn't written in a as simple, easy and maintainable way as possible. Our coding style guide have a whole section about "Avoid clever code" that stress the need for keeping code simple. At a review it's important to ensure that the code is functionally correct but it's equally important to ensure it's simple. A code base is maintained for decades ...

Comment: … and by different people at different levels of expertise.  So letting one very skilled person make complicated clever code will hurt all other. Obvious examples to avoid are `5[arr]` for array, swapping variables without using a temp, and many more. There is always a "grey zone" where it can be discussed whether some code is too "clever" but in that case we always look for a more simple implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You may also use function memcpy to get rid of newline.

The C library function void *memcpy(void *str1, const void *str2, size_t n) copies n characters from memory area str2 to memory area str1.

```
fgets(s, MAX, stdin);  
memcpy(search_for, s, strlen(s)-1);    
find_track(search_for);
```

You may add some error handling too.